# Can't connect multiple nodemcu to same broker

Tags: mqtt, esp8266, mosquitto, nodemcu

I am currently working on a project in which I use ESP8266 wifi modules with mqtt. I use a mosquitto broker installed on my computer.

I am trying to make more than one esp8266 modules subscribe to a certain topic on the broker.  I am using two modules as a demo.

The problem is that whenever I connect one of the modules, the other one disconnects from broker. When I re-connect it the first module (that has just been connected) goes offline.

Any help?

Comment: For problems like this it helps to include your connection code and the logs from the broker showing the clients getting disconnected in the question so we don't have to guess...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use unique client ids for each module. The broker will kick the first client off when the second connects with the same client id

Comment: His description of the problem exactly fits the symptoms of having clashing client ids. And in a esp8266 environment the odds of him having flashed exactly the same image to both devices is reasonably high, so just playing the odds (and it makes me look god like....)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem with the NodeMCU with the Arduino IDE while trying to connect two NodeMCUs to different topics, but for some reason the second NodeMCU would keep trying to connect to MQTT unsuccessfully.

After reading this post, I realized that I hadn't change the "id" and that

`if (client.connect("leftBlind", mqtt_user, mqtt_password)) {`

had been the same for both of my programs. I changed "leftBlind" to something else and it worked.